# SwitchPreference Using Wrong Switch Text

Tags: android, android-preferences

I have two switches set up in a preferences.xml file.

```
<SwitchPreference
        android:summaryOff="Metric Units"
        android:summaryOn ="Imperial Units"
        android:switchTextOff="Metric"
        android:switchTextOn="Imperial"
        android:key="unit_pref_imperial_on"
        android:title="Units"/>
<SwitchPreference
        android:summaryOff="Your battery levels are not being monitored."
        android:summaryOn ="Your battery levels are being monitored."
        android:switchTextOff="Off"
        android:switchTextOn="On"
        android:key="battery_pref"
        android:title="Battery Monitor"/>
```

However, the second switch sometimes uses the prior switches switchTextOn and switchTextOff values. It doesn't happen all the time, only sometimes?

Can anyone help me out here? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get around this, I decided to define my strings as an `@string` resource instead of just in the xml `android:text` section.

This seems to have cleared it up for me.